# How could I convert a Google Sheets in to a excel file?

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

I am trying to convert the attached document into a excel file ..

It contains a scrapped websites that is constantly updating ...

I want the same feature such as the conditional formatting to occur..

Could someone assist?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TekMW2g04xQJCmBY_rntJflXxGdxtHD7MxITr8L7lCA/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score -2):

> FILE > DOWNLOAD > MICROSOFT EXCEL

[image: convert a Google Sheets in to a excel file]